Having error LLVM ERROR: Symbol not found: __svml_erf4_ha when running python in Spyder
I am encountering this error when import an in-house module within Spyder:
import inhouse-module

The error shows:
LLVM ERROR: Symbol not found: __svml_erf4_ha
Fatal Python error: Aborted
The crash seems originated from numba package. When I am running the same code in VS Code, it goes through. I also tried following:
os.environ['NUMBA_DISABLE_INTEL_SVML'] = "1"
print(os.environ['NUMBA_DISABLE_INTEL_SVML'])

import inhouse-module

This error repeats.
What should I do?
